# pop-up using javascript with visits and sample rate not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to make a pop-up that only shows up:
after the third visit, and only 20% of the time.

I have this right now, and I'm not really great at Javascript and need some help figuring out exactly what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated

```
visits = getCookie('nVisits');
if (!visits) {
  visits = 1
}
if (visits == 3) {
  deleteCookie('nVisits')
  if (rand(0, 100) <= 20) {
    window.open("http://mypopup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
  } else {
    if (visits < 3) {
      ++visits;
      cookieData = visits;
      setCookie('nVisits', cookieData, expDate)
    }
  }
}
```

In the head of the page I set the cookie:

```
    expDate = new Date;
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days. 
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 180 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); expDate.toGMTString();  

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){

document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name){

var dc = document.cookie;
var prefix = name + "=";
var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
if (begin == -1){
begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
if (begin != 0) return null;}
else{begin += 2;}
var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
if (end == -1){end = dc.length;}
return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}


function deleteCookie(name, path, domain){

if (getCookie(name)){
document.cookie = name + "=" + 
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
"; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";}
}
```

----UPDATE---
I originally had this - which was working - it's just getting the random 20% to work...

```
<Script>
visits = getCookie('nVisits');
if (!visits){visits = 1};
if (visits == 3 ){deleteCookie('nVisits')
window.open("https://popup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");  
}
if (visits < 3){++visits;
cookieData = visits;
setCookie('nVisits',cookieData,expDate)
}
</Script>
```

Comment: What error is it generating, if any?

Comment: No error given, just not working.  I had it working before I put the  if (rand(0, 100) <= 20) part in - meaning it was working when visited 3 times, just can not figure out the 20% of visits.

Comment: Try Math.random() instead of rand()

Comment: did Math.random and now it's just popping up every third visit (ignoring the math.random)

Comment: Ok try this one instead: return Math.random() * (max - min) + min, obviously exchanging the max/min with your values.

Comment: ok, I did this?   if (Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) {    but nothing has changed?  I need it show up 20% of the time?

Comment: I mean: if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20) { } That should be the ticket :)

Comment: Thank you thank you!!!  I just messed up the formatting.  Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because I couln't find the definition for *your* function `rand`, I completely rewrote the snipped.

```
const visitsCookieName = 'nVisits';
let visits = getCookie(visitsCookieName) || 0;
if (visits === 3) {
    deleteCookie(visitsCookieName)
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) return;

    window.open("http://mypopup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    return;
}

setCookie(visitsCookieName, ++visits, expDate);
```

### Explanation

The random logic I'm using here is really simple. First I multiply the random float to 5 which return a float number between **0** and **~4.99**. After that we need the floored value of it. So it's between **0** and **4**. Because `0 == false` this hit only 20% of all tries.

Another problem in your snipped is on line 10 (`if (visits < 3) {`). This will never be true because in the upper statement you check if `if (visits == 3) {` (line 5) and because you didn't change the value of `visits` it can't be anything else but exactly **3**.

Comment: The thing is - that originally I had this and it worked after 3 visits, so thats not the issue (I don't think). It's trying to get the 20% in there:<Script>
visits = getCookie('nVisits');
if (!visits){visits = 1};
if (visits == 3 ){deleteCookie('nVisits')
window.open("https://mypopup.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");  
}
if (visits < 3){++visits;
cookieData = visits;
setCookie('nVisits',cookieData,expDate)
}
</Script>